# Why props.children are not rendered on the first render? I have to refresh the page, so then props.children appear on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on the web-app that has a role choice when you visit for the first time. After I choose the admin role for example, it sets the value of `userRole` in `localStorage`.

Here is App you can see that depending on the current role there are different routes.

After I have the role chosen, I'm redirected to the '/' route and I actually want to see the component that renders this route which is TableBoard in this case, but instead I firstly get `render={() => <Container>its from app.tsx {route.component}</Container>}`. So on the first render I only see `its from app.tsx`, then I refresh the page and everything is fine.

How to fix routing here?

Please ask if something is unclear.

```
function App() {
  const currentRole = useReduxSelector(state => state.auth.currentRole);
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  const role = localStorage.getItem('role');

  const getCurrentRoutes = () => {
    if (role === 'userCollaborator') {
      return AccRoutes;
    } else if (role === 'userAdmin') {
      return AdminRoutes;
    } else if (role === 'userHr') {
      return HRRoutes;
    } else if (role === 'userPartner') {
      return Routes;
    } else {
      return RoutesAuth;
    }
  };
  const routes = getCurrentRoutes();
  let routesComponents;
  if (currentRole && accessToken) {
    routesComponents = routes?.map(route => {
      return (
        <Route
          key={route.name}
          exact
          path={route.path}
          render={() => <Container>its from app.tsx {route.component}</Container>}
        />
      );
    });
  } else {
    routesComponents = routes?.map(route => {
      return (
        <Route
          key={route.name}
          exact
          path={route.path}
          component={route.component}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>{routesComponents}</Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component that should be rendered for the route I'm redirected:

```
export const TableBoard = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>here I have a lot of other content so it should be rendered as props.children in Container</div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

And the code for Components.tsx looks this way:

```
const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `localStorage.getItem('role')` won't make react rerender your component. You can make a provider to handle this situation.

For example:

```js
// RoleProvider.jsx

const RoleContext = React.createContext();

export const useRoleContext = () => {
  return React.useContext(RoleContext)
}

export default function RoleProvider({ children }) {
  const [role, setRole] = React.useState();
  
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      setRole(localStorage.getItem('role'));
    },
    [setRole]
  )

  const value = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ 
      role, 
      setRole: (role) => {
        localStorage.setItem('role', role);
        setRole(role);
      }
    }),
    [role, setRole]
  );

  return (
    <RoleContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </RoleContext>
  )
};
```

Then, you can put the `RoleProvider` above those children who need the role value. And use `const { role } = useRoleContext()` in those children. Since role is stored in a state. Whenever you update the role by the following code, those children who use `const { role } = useRoleContext()` will be rerendered.

```js
const { setRole } = useRoleContext();

// Please put it in a useEffect or handler function
// Or this will cause "Too many rerenders"
setRole('Some Role You Want')
```

Comment: Great. What if I have Redux here already been set up in this project, should I add the role into the Redux state then instead of setting into localStorage?

Comment: In my opinion, using `localStorage` and using `Redux` are for solving different problem. With `localStorage`, you can get the role immediately without waiting the api(I am assuming your project is a SPA). Without `localStorage`, you must send a request to your API server to get the role.